# MYSQL: Doing a where on a own defined parameter in SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, select, parameter-passing, where-clause

When I do a SELECT statement with an AS definement and i want to filter on that it give the folowing error:  #1054 - Unknown column 'TimeInSeconds' in 'where clause'

Code:

```
Select Id, time/10000000 as TimeInSeconds FROM Results WHERE
TimeInSeconds > 5 AND
TimeInSeconds < 36000
```

I understand the error that TimeInSeconds is not part of the original table, but are there ways to work with these defined collumns?

Comment: You can either use `WHERE time/10000000...` or put it in a subquery...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `HAVING` clause to filter out the results of custom aliases

```
Select Id, `time`/10000000 as TimeInSeconds 
FROM Results 
HAVING TimeInSeconds > 5 AND TimeInSeconds < 36000
```

Or repeat the expression using `WHERE` clause

```
Select Id, `time`/10000000 as TimeInSeconds 
FROM Results 
WHERE (`time`/10000000) > 5 AND (`time`/10000000) < 36000
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to put the results in a `subquery`:

```
Select Id, timeinseconds
From (Select Id, time/10000000 as TimeInSeconds FROM Results) t
Where TimeInSeconds > 5 AND TimeInSeconds < 36000
```

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to do this is:

```
select id, time/10000000 TimeInSeconds
from results
where time > 5 * 10000000
and time < 36000 * 10000000
```

The reason is the your field is being compared directly to values.  The subquery method selects the whole darn table before filtering the results.  Doing math on a field in the where clause, like using formulas, tends to be slow.

This is even more significant if the field in question is indexed.